# how to set 9000 characters in nvarchar(max)

Tags: sql-server

I need to set 9000 characters in nvarchar variable

```
declare @inXMLRequest xml

declare @insertsql nvarchar(max)

set @insertsql='--------9000 characters--------'
EXEC sp_executesql   @insertsql,
                   N'@inXMLRequest XML OUTPUT', 
                     @inXMLRequest OUTPUT 
print @insertsql
```

But NVARCHAR is taking 5000 characters only
how to set 9000 characters in NVARCHAR variable?

Comment: I thought nvarchars max length is 4000.

Comment: @Vilx: you're right, i'm blind :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to All,

Insted of using SP_Executesql directly we Executing nvarchar variable

Above we Are preparing  @insertsql nvarchar variable morethan 8000 characters and it is giving to sp_executesql like this

EXEC sp_executesql @insertsql, N'@inXMLRequest XML OUTPUT',@inXMLRequest OUTPUT

insted of above query  replaced with below query

```
Exec ('DeClare @inXMLRequest XML SET @inXMLRequest='------above 8000 characters---')
```

Finally we will execute that nvarchar string and get out put

Answer (score 1):

if you write a small program that tries the same thing outside the management studio you will be able to do this.

unfortunately for some reason it is not possible to do this with a insert statement in the management studio. there is a 4k limit on what you put into the management studio.

I've people do inserts before, ie, first insert 4k chars then the next 4k chars etc

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but you cant store such long rows in varchar.
a row have to fit into a db-page. 
varchar fields are stored in the same page, where the row is stored.
a page is usually smaller than 8192 bytes (depending on db-system)

there a some exceptions like blob fields which are not stored in the same page of a row.

you should use a other data type like text/blob/image.

nvarchar 9000 is btw. impossible this will allocate 18000 byte which dont fit into a page.
this is the reason for the 4000 char limit.